# Kindle or Kobo syncing content

Tags: e-reader

I'm looking for an ereader that can easily sync content with a laptop. It should function similar to dropbox: copy a PDF in a folder, and it should upload automatically to the ereader - if wifi is connected of course. So connecting a USB cable is not an option.

Currently I have a Sony PRS T3 ereader, and I'm very fond of it. Only problem is that it's such a hassle to copy files to it.

I wonder if Amazon or Kobo have solved this problem, and how it works out. The reader should be an e-ink reader, not a Kindle Fire with Android.

Answer (score 1):

I use the basic version of **Kindle**

It can do all the following things:

- copy a PDF in a folder
- formats and uploads it to the e-reader.

In addition, I use an app called [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) which makes that process very simple and effortless. I generally use epub version books, compatible with iBooks. However, Calibre formats them according to Kindle's format and uploads them to the device.

So, copying files is a breeze with (Kindle + Calibre).

Comment: Thank you. I use Calibre as well. I would like to do this without using Calibre, and without using a cable.